# KafkaListner Unit Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, apache-kafka

I have the following method to consume data from a Kafka topic.

```
    @KafkaListener(
            groupId = "<group-id>",
            topics = "<topic>",
            concurrency = "<concurrency>",
    )
    public void listen(
            Acknowledgment ack,
            @Payload final ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) int partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset,
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_KEY, required = false) String key,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic
    ) throws IOException {

        // Consumes the data with consumerRecord and doing the rest of the stuff

        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

I need to write a unit test for this. What I am trying to do is publish some data to a test topic and test if it is consumed by this listener. How can I do it?

Trying to find a solution on this.

Comment: There's a whole section of the docs on testing. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#reference

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not unit testing.

Unit tests are when you mock your entire environment and call the method you are testing directly:

```
@InjectMocks
Listener listener;

@Mock
Handler handler;

@Test
void givenSomething() {
    var id = UUID.randomUUID();
    listener.listen(id);
    verify(handler).handle(id);
}
```

If you want to test the listener with a real kafka broker, these are integration tests and you need to prepare a test environment for this.

To do this, you can use a testcontainers or a separate docker-compose file that will run before your tests so that the real environment does not mix with the test one.

[testcontainers](https://testcontainers.com/)

[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Additionally, there is also a spring-kafka-test library that allows you to write integration tests with kafka that resides in the application's memory.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka-test

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: groupName
test:
  topic: test-topic
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducer producer;

    @Value("${test.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Test
    public void givenEmbeddedKafkaBroker_whenSendingWithSimpleProducer_thenMessageReceived() 
      throws Exception {
        String data = "Sending with our own simple KafkaProducer";
        
        producer.send(topic, data);
        
        boolean messageConsumed = consumer.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertTrue(messageConsumed);
        assertThat(consumer.getPayload(), containsString(data));
    }
}
```

You can see more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-testing

Comment: spring-kafka also supports unit tests

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok, then show the code where you write a pure unit test, without using SpringBootTest?
Yes, there is spring-kafka-test, but how does this contradict what I wrote? This library will raise kafka in memory and make it possible to interact with it, but this is not unit testing, but integration. And this does not change the approach that I described.

Comment: Kafka comes with [MockConsumer and MockProducer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#mock-cons-prod) already. Don't need external libraries like Mockito. Similarly, TopologyTestDriver for Kafka Steams doesn't use a broker